# How to Callback socket.io client using sails.sockets.js onconnect event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

Am not able to call socket-client listener using sails.sockets.js onConnect event on server side..

E.g

```
onConnect: function(session, socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        console.log("socket.id: " + socket.id);
        sails.sockets.broadcast(socket.id, 'chat message', {msg:msg});
    });
}
```

Please let me know whats the correct way of calling back to your socket-client using socket-server events like onConnect..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard sails.js socket library:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    io.socket.on('connect', function() {

    });


    io.socket.on('chat message', function(data) {
        io.socket.post('/routeToAction', {

        }, function(data, jwres) {

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for newer version, you have to use config/bootstrap.js file for listen events

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) { 

    // handle connect socket first event executes after logged in
    sails.io.on('connect', function (socket){
        // store facebook token here
    });

    // handle custom listener for other stuff
    sails.io.on('doSomeStuff', function (socket){
        // check facebook token match with requested token
    });
cb();
};
```

client : you can simple emit "doSomeStuff" after logged in with facebook and pass token with each request

Answer (score 0):

Finally am become little expert in web sockets who knows back anf forth of push technoligy via websockets..

How to start with websockets : 
Step 1: Choose any websocket framework for your application and install socket client on client side and socker server on server side with listeners(imp.).

Step 2: Once you are ready with socket setup on both sides then your client/browser will make a connection after every page load which is listened on server side via onConnect listener or event.

Step 3: Successfull connection on both sides giving you socket object which contains each client socket id which is managed at server side to either join any channel/room or just to make a broadcast or blast.
Remember:

i. Socket object is responsible for defining listeners on both client side and server side. Using socket object you can pass any data to listeners.

ii. Socket connection is very helpful when you trying to push data from client to server and vice-versa.

iii. You can make your small chatter tool with it once you understand as mentioned above.

Will share similar working snippet soon..

//onConnect event on server side
  onConnect: function(session, socket) {
     console.log("Socket Connect Successfully: " + socket.id );

```
socket.on('chatAgency', function(data){
sails.sockets.broadcast(data.agencyId,"chatAgency",  {message:data.message,agencyId:session.agencyId});
});
```

},